# What's unclear about this question on how to configure Acrobat so that it runs an Acrobat Javascript script whenever a PDF is opened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked the [question](https://superuser.com/q/1701663/116475):

> I wrote an Acrobat Javascript script. How can I configure Acrobat so that it runs a Acrobat Javascript script whenever a PDF is opened in Acrobat?

It was closed as "needs details or clarity". What's unclear about this question? No closevoter left any comment.

Comment: What have you tried? What make you believe it is possible? Have you inserted your script into a PDF? Your question is pretty content free and shows no personal effort or research.

Comment: @Mokubai Is "shows no personal effort or research. " a reason to close?

Comment: It can be if we have no way to know if it is possible. It is largely up to you to prove you are using the program in a way that it is intended to work.

Comment: @Mokubai How does "showing personal effort or research" can show you that I believe it is possible?

Comment: @Mokubai someone indicated an answer in the comment section. Could you reopen The question so that the answer can be written as an answer and not as a comment?

Comment: Reopened.......